# Pointers: Expression is not assignable

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

I'm writing a function whose purpose is to change the value of struct variables. I'm getting error messages that say the expressions toward the end of my first function are not assignable. How, then, do I have the function change the values of the daate structure?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

struct date dateUpdate (struct date *dait) {
    struct date tomorrow;
    int numberOfDays (struct date d);

    if (dait->day != numberOfDays (*dait) ) {
        tomorrow.day = dait->day + 1;
        tomorrow.month = dait->month;
        tomorrow.year = dait->year;
    }
    else if ( dait->month == 12 ) { //end of year
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = 1;
        tomorrow.year = dait->year + 1;
    }
    else { //end of month
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = dait->month + 1;
        tomorrow.year = dait->year;
    }

    &dait->day = tomorrow.day;
    &dait->month = tomorrow.month;
    &dait->year = tomorrow.year;

    return *dait;
}

//Function to find the number of days in a month;

int numberOfDays (struct date d)
{
    int days;
    bool isLeapYear (struct date d);
    const int daysPerMonth[12] = 
    { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    if ( isLeapYear (d) && d.month == 2 )
        days = 29;
    else
        days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];

    return days;
}

}

int main (void) {
    struct date daate;
    daate.day = 21;
    daate.month = 6;
    daate.year = 2013;

    dateUpdate(&daate);
    printf("%d", daate.day);
}
```

Comment: Why is dateUpdate() returning a value when you're passing by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax (which you already used in the function) is the following

```
dait->day = tomorrow.day;
dait->month = tomorrow.month;
dait->year = tomorrow.year;
```

Take into account that instead of these three statements you could write simply

```
*dait = tomorrow;
```

Answer (score 0):

`dait` is already a pointer, so `&dait` is a pointer to a pointer, and thus it has no fields to de-reference.

Solution: lose the `&` before `dait`.